# Are there any decent libraries for generating web documents in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, msdn

I'm looking at generating web-documents at runtime. This means generating the html, and JavaScript and css. Are there any advanced libraries? Or am I going to be going at by creating the html document with File.Create("Default.aspx") and then lots of HtmlTextWriter.WriteBlaBlaBla()

Comment: I think your question would be better served by elaborating on the use case behind this desire. Generating .aspx pages on the fly is almost never necessary, so it might be confusing to others as to why you would want to take this approach in the first place, and might also contribute to the lack of resources dedicated to this particular task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your business requirement seems unclear but try using HTMLtextwriter to have more control over your code